# Adobe ExtendScript debugging

Tags: adobe, extendscript

There's a dearth of info in the supporting PDFs and on the web.  I happened to come across a post in a blog that mentioned that $.write() or $.writeln() will write a string to the javascript console.  Quite useful. Does anyone know if this $ object has any additional properties or methods?

Comment: I dabbed a little bit in JSX for Photoshop & Illustrator. There's documentation and the ObjectModel under Help is handy, but when I tried the same with Soundbooth, I found no documentation, that is how I found $.writeln(), $ seems to be a reference to whatever application your connected to(Photoshop, Illustrator, etc.), otherwise it points to the ExtendScript itself I think, not sure. Try this for kicks :) :

$.writeln(inspect($));
function inspect(o){
 var result = '';
 for(var i in o) result += i + ': ' + o[i]+'\n';
 return result;
}

Comment: Actually, $ is just a reserved symbol in the ExtendScript language for ExtendScript specific functionality.  It behaves the same across all the applications.  For more details, consult the "JavaScript Tools Guide", in particular the "ExtendScript Tools and Features" section.

Answer (score 2):

I just answered my own question. JavaScript Tools Guide CS4.pdf. Chapter 8 ExtendScript Tools and Features has all I need. Just getting started with Adobe scripting and I'm a bit overwhelmed with the huge array of elements in a CS4 install.

Answer (score 1):

Bits of Photoshop are implemented in ExtendScript.  If you look in the folder

`[apps folder]/Adobe Photoshop CS4/Presets/Scripts/`

You'll find several scripts that may be useful as sample code.